# Is there some theorem/identity that $\lVert X \rVert_F^2 = \sum_i \lVert x_i \rVert_2^2 $, where $X = [x_1,\cdots,x_n] \in M_{m,n}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for asking basic question.

Is there some theorem/identity that $\lVert X \rVert_F^2 = \sum_i \lVert x_i \rVert_2^2 $, where $X = [x_1,\cdots,x_n] \in M_{m,n}$  and $x_i \in M_{m,1}$?

At least it is true numerically.

EDIT: $\lVert \cdot \rVert_F$ corresponds to Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true by definition:
$$
\|X\|_F^2=tr(X^t.X)=\sum\limits_i <x_i,x_i>=\sum\limits_i \|x_i\|_2^2
$$

note: as $\|X^t\|_F^2=\|X\|_F^2$ you can also do the same with rows instead of your columns $x_i$

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome :)